# The best way to let user go to another webpage after 2 minutes

Tags: jquery

How can I do that with HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery?  Thanks a lot

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { window.location = 'other website' }, 120000)`

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @adeneo Isn't that no longer approved by W3C?  Thanks.

Comment: No it's fine. Not sure you'd think that. The W3C have nothing to do with JS anyway.

Comment: @adeneo In that case, excuse me for my inexperience.  :) hahahaa

Comment: setTimeout(function (){window.location.replace("www.stackoverflow.com");}, 120000);

Comment: @adeneo can I use it to refresh only one part of the page using ajax as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=your url" />
```

60 are seconds

Comment: While this may answer the question, its not clear why this would achieve what the OP is looking for. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and expand on your answer.